# Problems with vpn in Jammy Jelly

Tags: networking, vpn, connection, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm having trouble with a VPN (https://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn). I import the data from the file, put the loggin and password and when I activate the VPN I receive a "failure to activate the network connection".

Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be that vpnbook has yet published an update for 22.04 as with nordvpn. For nordvpn, open the terminate and copy and past  `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/bin/systemd-resolve` solved the problem for me. You can give it a try.

Comment: didn't work. I suspect I'll wait patiently.

Comment: I try to use this: `sudo openvpn vpnbook-pl226-tcp80.ovpn` but I get this:  2022-04-30 17:27:11 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.                     2022-04-30 17:27:11 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP  2022-04-30 17:27:11 OpenSSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak  2022-04-30 17:27:11 Cannot load inline certificate file                                        2022-04-30 17:27:11 Exiting due to fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help?

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701185
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xl2tpd/+bug/1968336

You can try downgrade package xl2tpd

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think I wait for a few days.